# How to read/write from a tcp header bin file

Tags: c, tcp, bin, read-write

I need some help on a program that I have to create for school. I don't know exactly how to go about reading in and manipulating data from a bin file. The bin file is in the form of a TCP header and I need to:

1. Read the binary file into a struct and print the header.
2. Create a response header and write it to a new file.
3. Read the response binary file and print the header.

This is what I have so far:

```
struct tcp
{
    unsigned char sourceport[2];
    unsigned char destination[2];
    unsigned char sequence[4];
    unsigned char ackno[4];
    unsigned char other[2];
    unsigned char window[2];
    unsigned char checksum[2];
    unsigned char urgent[2];
} my_header;

int readfile(char filename[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int pointer, i;
    unsigned char buffer[20];
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(!fp){ return 1; }

    fread(&my_header, sizeof(my_header), 1, fp);
    i = 0;
    pointer = 0;

    while (pointer < 2)
    {
        my_header.sourceport[pointer] = buffer[pointer];
        pointer++;
    }

    while (pointer < 4)
    {
        my_header.destination[pointer - 2] = buffer[pointer];
        pointer++;
    }

    while(pointer < 8)
    {
        my_header.sequence[pointer - 4] = buffer[pointer];
        pointer++;
    }

    while(pointer < 12)
    {
        my_header.ackno[pointer - 8] = buffer[pointer];
        pointer++;
    }

    while(pointer < 14)
    {
        my_header.other[pointer - 12] = buffer[pointer];
        pointer++;
    }
    while(pointer < 16)
    {
        my_header.window[pointer - 14] = buffer[pointer];
        pointer++;
    }

    while(pointer < 18)
    {
        my_header.checksum[pointer - 16] = buffer[pointer];
        pointer++;
    }

    while(pointer < 20)
    {
        my_header.urgent[pointer - 18] = buffer[pointer];
        pointer++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    int check;
    unsigned char swap[2];
    check = readfile("test.bin");

    /* Checking for file to read */
    if(check == 0)
    {
        printf("File successfully read\n");
    }

    /* If file is not found */
    if(check == 1)
    {
        printf("Cannot open/find file.\n");
    }

    strcpy(swap,my_header.sourceport);
    strcpy(my_header.sourceport, my_header.destination);
    strcpy(my_header.destination, swap);
    writefile("test.bin");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your `readfile` function.

The main problem is that you are taking values in buffer (which are unassigned) and writing those garbage values into your struct fields.  You're passing in the address of `my_header` instead of `buffer`.

Also, you're not checking the return value of `fread()`, so you don't know if the call failed or if it returned enough bytes.

As it turns out, reading directly into `my_header` is actually the preferred way to handle this.  Assuming the read was successful and the struct fields are the same size and in the same order as the file contents, you don't need to do anything else.  The structure is already populated.

So your function should look like this:

```
int readfile(char filename[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int bytes_read;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        perror("fopen failed");
        return 1;
    }

    bytes_read = fread(&my_header, sizeof(my_header), 1, fp);
    if (bytes_read == -1) {
        perror("fread failed");
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    } else if (bytes_read != sizeof(my_header)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "expected to read %d bytes, actually read %d\n", sizeof(my_header), bytes_read);
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Note the use of `perror` to print detailed error messages for `fopen` and `fread`, and ensuring to call `fclose(fp)` in error cases after the file has been opened.

Edit:

The struct contains char arrays, however they are not strings but arrays of bytes, so you can't use `strcpy` or other string manipulation functions on them.  You can however use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(swap,my_header.sourceport, 2);
memcpy(my_header.sourceport, my_header.destination, 2);
memcpy(my_header.destination, swap, 2);
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I was thinking that I had to read in the entire bin file first straight into an array and then parse it. Also, how would I go about manipulating the arrays in the struct? I have them as char arrays, would I need to use strcpy?. I'm just trying to read in bits of data. Supposedly from a bin file that contains a tcp header.